# Задача из Primer Plus C++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, visual-studio-2010

Здравствуйте, не получается решить задачу.

Условие:

The Wine class has a string class object member (see Chapter 4) that holds the name of a wine and a `Pair` object (as discussed in this chapter) of `valarray<int>` objects (as discussed in this chapter).The first member of each `Pair` object holds the vintage years,and the second member holds the numbers of bottles owned for the corresponding particular vintage year.For example,the first valarray object of the Pair object might hold the years 1988,1992,and 1996,and the second valarray object might hold the bottle counts 24,48,and 144.It may be convenient for Wine to have an int member that stores the number of years.Also some typedefs might be useful to simplify the coding:

```
typedef std::valarray<int> ArrayInt;

typedef Pair<ArrayInt, ArrayInt> PairArray;
```

Thus,the `PairArray` type represents type `Pair<std::valarray<int>, std::valarray<int> >`.Implement the Wine class by using containment.The class should have a default constructor and at least the following constructors:

```
// initialize label to l, number of years to y,

// vintage years to yr[], bottles to bot[]

Wine(const char * l, int y, const int yr[], const int bot[]);

// initialize label to l, number of years to y, 

// create array objects of length y 

Wine(const char * l, int y);
```

The Wine class should have a method `GetBottles()` that,given a Wine object with y years,prompts the user to enter the corresponding number of vintage years and bottle counts.A method `Label()` should return a reference to the wine name.A method `sum()` should return the total number of bottles in the second `valarray<int>` object in the `Pair` object.

Вот мой код:

Заголовочный файл:

```
#ifndef WINE_H_
#define WINE_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>
#include <string>


class Wine
{
private:
    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    class Pair
    {
    private:
        T1 a;
        T2 b;
    public:
        T1 & first() { return a; }
        T2 & second() { return b; }
        T1 first() const { return a; }
        T2 second() const { return b; }
        Pair(const T1 & aval, const T2 & bval) : a(aval), b(bval) {}
        Pair() {}
    };

    typedef std::valarray<int> ArrayInt;
    typedef Pair<ArrayInt, ArrayInt> PairArray;

    std::string label;
    int year;
    PairArray vb;
public:
    Wine() : label("no name"), year(0), vb() {}
    ~Wine() {}
    Wine(const char * l, int y, const int yr[], const int bot[]);
    Wine(const char * l, int y);
    void GetBottles();
    std::string & Label() { return label; }
    int sum() const;
    void Show() const;
};



#endif
```

Реализация методов:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "wine.h"


Wine::Wine(const char * l, int y, const int yr[], const int bot[]) : label(l), year(y)
{
    vb(ArrayInt(y), ArrayInt(y));
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
    {
        vb.first()[i] = yr[i];
        vb.second()[i] = bot[i];
    }
}

Wine::Wine(const char * l, int y) : label(l), year(y), vb(ArrayInt(0, y), ArrayInt(0, y)) {}

void Wine::GetBottles()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < year; i++)
    {
    std::cout << "Enter the vintage year: ";
    std::cin >> vb.first()[i];
    std::cout << "Enter the number of bottles: ";
    std::cin >> vb.second()[i];
    }
}

int Wine::sum() const
{
    return vb.second().sum();
}

void Wine::Show() const
{
    std::cout << "Wine: " << label << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Year" << '\t' << "Bottles" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < year; i++)
    {
        std::cout << vb.first()[i] << '\t' << vb.second()[i];
    }
}
```

Программа, которая должна заработать по заданию:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "wine.h"


int main ( void )
{
    using std::cin;
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
    cout << "Enter name of wine: ";
    char lab[50];

    cin.getline(lab, 50);
    cout << "Enter number of years: ";
    int yrs;
    cin >> yrs;
    Wine holding(lab, yrs);
    holding.GetBottles(); 
    holding.Show();        
    const int YRS = 3;
    int y[YRS] = {1993, 1995, 1998};
    int b[YRS] = { 48, 60, 72}; 
    Wine more("Gushing Grape Red",YRS, y, b); 
    more.Show(); 
    cout << "Total bottles for " << more.Label() 
        << ": " << more.sum() << endl; 
    cout << "Bye\n"; 
    return 0;
}
```

Visual Studio подчеркивает только объект в конструкторе

`vb(ArrayInt(y), ArrayInt(y));`

Хотя здесь вроде все норм

```
Wine::Wine(const char * l, int y) : label(l), year(y), vb(ArrayInt(0, y), ArrayInt(0, y)) {}
```

Comment: Вы не хотите перевести вопрос на русский?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приведенная строчка

vb(ArrayInt(y), ArrayInt(y));

неверна.

Вы пытаетесь вызвать конструктор для объекта, который уже создан конструктором по умолчанию.

Надо вставить вызов нужного Вам конструктора в список инициализации.

То есть: 
Wine::Wine(const char * l, int y, const int yr[], const int bot[]) : label(l), year(y), vb(ArrayInt(y), ArrayInt(y)) 
{
...